# Determine the stability of $(x,y)=(0,0)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, systems-of-equations

Determine the stability of $(x,y)=(0,0)$:

1/$$\bf{\begin{cases}
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{x}= -2x-y+2xy^2-3x^3\\ 
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{y}= \dfrac{x}{3}-y-x^2y-7y^3
\end{cases} \tag {1}}$$

2/ 
$$\bf{\begin{cases}
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{x}= x-xy^4\\ 
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{y}= y-x^2y^3
\end{cases} \tag {2}}$$

I'm trying to find a **Liapunov function** $V(x,y)=???$. But I have no solution! :( Anyone can post a few hints (like $V(x,y)=?$)

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: You realize that you cannot always find one, correct? Do you know one exists for each of these cases? Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

If we look at phase portraits for the two systems, we have:

[image]

[image]

From these, we can see there is a single critical point for the first and it looks well behaved, so there is a chance we can find one.

Hint: Try $V(x, y) = ax^2 + by^2$ and see if you can resolve $a$ and $b$.

For the second one, there are a lot of things going on in the phase portrait due to five critical points. I doubt you will be able to find one for this as it is all over the map. Also, it is clear the CP is unstable by just looking at the direction fields, but you can do an eigenvalue analysis of the Jacobian at $(0,0)$ to also see that.

Comment: Did you figure out a. with the hint? What did you get for $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @kimtahe6: What book do these problems come from? Regards

Comment: @ **Amzoti**: I don't know what book do these problems come from :( Because these are my homework (since my professor :) . He had read in my class and he didn't tell us it from the book.

Comment: @ **Amzoti**: Why you said that "I may have given a bad hint on the other problem and am looking at if for V"? What does it mean?

Comment: @kimtahe6: I was not totally awake yet! The hint was perfect. Recall, the claim I made is that you could get this to work for the first, since there is only ONE critical point and it is well behaved (even in that case, I am not sure it is always possible to find $V$). For the second one, there are five critical points and it will not be possible to find such a $V$ as the answer describes. Is this clear?

Comment: You mean: For the second one, we have 5 critical points $(x,y) \in \{(0,0);(1,1);(-1,-1);(1,-1);(-1,1)\}$. So we will not be able to find $V(x,y)$.

Comment: @kimtahe6: Imagine that you are trying to find a global V to check for stability. You are surrounded by saddle points and the point $(0,0)$ is unstable (did you do the Jacobian and analyze it at that point). Do you think it would be possible to find such a $V$ in this case?

Comment: Yes, you're right! **Amzoti** I mean that you say true! :)

Comment: I have an example: $$\bf{\begin{cases}
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{x}= -xy^4\\ 
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{y}= x^4y
\end{cases} \tag {3}}$$. Since your hint, I can find $V(x,y)=x^2-y^2$. Is it correct? **Amzoti**

Comment: Recall the three conditions you need for $V$. :-) Are they all met here for all $(x,y)$ in your choice?

Comment: Hihi, 3 conditions : 1/ $V(t,0) \equiv 0$ ; 2/ $V(t,x) \ge a(\|x\|)$ and 3/ $\dot{V}(t,x) \le 0$, I forgot condition (2). :)

Comment: If you draw a phase portrait, you will see that $x=0$ and $y=0$ cause problems for finding such a function. I do not think you can find one in this case, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Ok! For system: $$\bf{\begin{cases}
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{x}= -xy^4\\ 
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{y}= x^4y
\end{cases} \tag {3}}$$ . I have found $V(x,y)=x^4+y^4+x^2$. And you're wrong! **Amzoti**.

Comment: @kimtahe6: I did warn you that it may be possible (see my comment). I checked it and it works. Good find.

Comment: @ **Amzoti**: For system of equations: $$\bf{\begin{cases}
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{x}= -xy^4\\ 
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{y}= x^4y
\end{cases} \tag {3}}$$ I choose $V(x,y)=x^4+y^4$. 1/ I checked $$a(\|(x,y)\|)=\dfrac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{2} \le V(x,y) \le b(\|(x,y)\|)=(x^2+y^2)^2$$. Hence, $a(r)=\dfrac{r^4}{2},b(r)=r^4$. 2/ And $\dot{V}(x,y)= 0$. Therefore, $x \equiv 0$ is Uniformly stable. My solution is correct? Thanks!

Comment: For the system: $$\bf{\begin{cases}
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{x}= -2x-y+2xy^2-3x^3\\ 
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{y}= \dfrac{x}{3}-y-x^2y-7y^3
\end{cases} \tag {1}}$$ . Since your hints, I found $V(x,y)=x^2+3y^2$. And $x\equiv 0$ is **Uniformly Asymptotically Stable**. Is that correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

For system of equations: $$\bf{\begin{cases}
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{x}= x-xy^4\\ 
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{y}= y-x^2y^3
\end{cases} \tag {2}}$$

We use the **Chetaev** theorem to prove this.
Let the function $V(x,y)$ have the form $$V(x,y)=x^2-y^2$$

This function is positive definite in the subdomain $\mathcal{V}$ in which the inequality $|x| > |y|$ holds.

We calculate the derivative $\dfrac{dV}{dt}$ by virtue of the system and define its sign in the subdomain $\mathcal{V}$.

$$\dot{V}(x,y)=2(x^2-y^2)=2V(x,y)$$

- It can be seen that the derivative $\dfrac{dV}{dt}$ is also positive definite in the subdomain $\mathcal{V}$ defined by the relation $|x| > |y|$.
- Besides that, the function $V(x,y)$ is zero on the boundary of $\mathcal{V}$ including the point $(0,0)$.

So, all conditions of the **Chetaev** theorem are fulfilled. Therefore, the zero solution of the system is *unstable*.

============================================

Is that ok? **Amzoti**